# MySQL Query Incorrect Count

Tags: mysql, select

I have a phone call database that has a field 'direction', named appropriately after the direction the call is going (in OR out). My problem is, when I do a search for either 'in' or 'out' calls, the number is completely wrong.

Example: 
For the month of May,
 
TOTAL calls (in + out) : 13622
 
IN calls : 12637
OUT calls : 985

```
SELECT `start`, `direction`, `ref_id` 
FROM  `call_list` 
WHERE  `did` = 'xxxx' 
AND  `start` >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' 
AND  `start` < '2013-06-01 00:00:00'
```

The above is an accurate count based on dumping the above query to CSV and actually looking at the list. However, when I add in the 'direction' search, the numbers returned are completely off:

```
SELECT `start`, `direction`, `ref_id` 
FROM  `call_list` 
WHERE  `did` = 'xxxx' 
AND  `start` >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' 
AND  `start` < '2013-06-01 00:00:00' 
AND `direction` = 'In'
```

...will result in a total count of 13461, and

```
SELECT `start`, `direction`, `ref_id` 
FROM  `call_list` 
WHERE  `did` = 'xxxx' 
AND  `start` >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' 
AND  `start` < '2013-06-01 00:00:00' 
AND `direction` = 'Out'
```

..yields a total count of 11018.

Consequently, if I group:

```
SELECT `direction`, count(*)
FROM  `call_list` 
WHERE  `did` =  'xxxx'
AND  `start` >=  '2013-05-01 00:00:00'
AND  `start` <  '2013-06-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY `direction`
```

...I get the correct count for each which is all well and good except sometimes I need to run queries on the 'In' or 'Out' count separately and so my numbers are off.

The 'direction' column is varchar(3) utf8_unicode_ci.

If anyone can shed light on why I am receiving bum count numbers, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have records where direction is null?

Comment: nope, only 'In' and 'Out'

Comment: can you make an SQL fiddle ?

Comment: any space etc. in the values?

Comment: as its a varchar3 i would say not as out should fill it

Comment: Something you're not telling us... Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c28a/3)** that shows that your queries work just fine. Do you by any chance `JOIN` this table with other tables in your real query?

Comment: correct, I even tried LIKE '%ut%' etc... to see if that would do anything different

Comment: To be sure, do a SELECT DISTINCT(direction) from call_list and see you get only 2 results.

Comment: for readability also I would suggest you use and `start` BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-01 00:00:00'

Comment: no joining. The query is essentially as typed above, except referencing my own 'did' numbers

Comment: Well then use a sqlfiddle that I provided as a base and create one that reproduces your problem, post a link to it in your question and we'll help you it fix.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle, @peterm, and that's how I expect it to operate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wild guess but one of the common causes of getting more or less rows than expected is using `OR`s in your `WHERE` conditionals without proper parentheses

E.g.

```
SELECT `start`, `direction`, `ref_id` 
  FROM  `call_list` 
WHERE  `did` = 'xxxx' OR `did` = 'yyyy'  -- << here is the problem !!!
  AND  `start` >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' 
  AND  `start` < '2013-06-01 00:00:00' 
  AND `direction` = 'In'
```

that should be

```
SELECT `start`, `direction`, `ref_id` 
  FROM  `call_list` 
WHERE  (`did` = 'xxxx' OR `did` = 'yyyy') 
  AND  `start` >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' 
  AND  `start` < '2013-06-01 00:00:00' 
  AND `direction` = 'In'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/956f3/4)** demo

Comment: wow, you are absolutely right. can't believe I missed that one. I had a foreach making the query and the one I was looking at had multiple did values with no trailing or leading parentheses but I was doing the search manually with only one did value. thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @JonCAMS You're very welcome :) BTW you might consider using `IN()` instead of multiple `OR`s like `...WHERE did IN('xxxx', 'yyyy', ...)`. It may simplify your life a little bit.